# Scrolling on Iphone (Apple products) browser

Tags: jquery, iphone, iframe, scroll, swipe

I have a Carousel of iframes that needs swiping enabled, but the swiping interacts with the events inside the iFrame.

To resolve this I added a transparent overlay div over the iframe, that performs the swiping. The problem occurs when i try to click a link from the iframe. What i'm doing is:

1. Catch the event - div clicked
2. Hide the div for 500ms so that the actual link can be clicked
3. Re-display the transparent div

```
$('.overlay-div').on('click touchstart', function () {
          $(this).hide();
          window.setTimeout(function () {
              $(".overlay-div").show();
          }, 500);
      });
```

On web and android browsers, when a link from the iframe is clicked, this works flawless, as it removes the div and performs the click as **one action**.

However, on iphone browsers, clicking the link removes the transparent div, but it never actually visits the link (so a minimum of 2 clicks is required). Links are just a minor issue here, as it also interferes with things like scrolling.

I read that there could be issues with clicking non-clickable elements on iphones, and that cursor - pointer may help, but it did not.